# Why are some of my tokens not being recognized?

Tags: python, lex, lexer, ply

I'm trying to build a simple HTML lexer, and I've defined my tokens like this:

```
tokens = [
    'text',
    'num',
    'id',
    'url',
    'newline',
    'space',
    'bigger',
    'sp',
    'del',
    'vert',
    'carr',

 ]

reserved = {'<html lang = "en"':"html_open", '<h1': 'h1_open', '</h1>':'h1_close','<p': 'p_open',
              '</p': 'p_close', '<body': 'body_open', 'id=': 'id_att', '</body': 'body_close' }

tokens = tokens+list(reserved.values())

t_bigger = '>'
t_newline = r'[\n]'
t_sp = r'[\s]'
t_del = r'[\d]'
t_vert = r'[\v]'
t_carr = r'[\r]'

def t_text(t):
     r'[a-zA-Z_0-9_<_ _"_=_/][ a-zA-Z_0-9_<_ _"_=_/]*'
     t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'text')    
     return t

def t_id(t):
     r'[a-zA-Z_0-9_<_"][a-zA-Z_0-9_"]*'
     t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'id')
     return t

def t_num(t):
     r'\d'
     t.value = int(t.value)
     return t

def t_error(t):
    print ("invalid char '%s'" %t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)
```

The text I'm using to test is:

```
<html lang = "en">
<body> 
    <h1 id="someid"> This is a test </h1> 
    <p> Paragraph </p> 
</body>
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
LexToken(html_open,'<html lang = "en"',1,0)
LexToken(bigger,'>',1,17)
LexToken(sp,'\r',1,18)
LexToken(newline,'\n',1,19)
LexToken(body_open,'<body',1,20)
LexToken(bigger,'>',1,25)
LexToken(text,' ',1,26)
LexToken(sp,'\r',1,27)
LexToken(newline,'\n',1,28)
LexToken(sp,'\t',1,29)
LexToken(text,'<h1 id="someid"',1,30)
LexToken(bigger,'>',1,45)
LexToken(text,' This is a test </h1',1,46)
LexToken(bigger,'>',1,66)
LexToken(text,' ',1,67)
LexToken(sp,'\r',1,68)
LexToken(newline,'\n',1,69)
LexToken(sp,'\t',1,70)
LexToken(p_open,'<p',1,71)
LexToken(bigger,'>',1,73)
LexToken(text,' Paragraph </p',1,74)
LexToken(bigger,'>',1,88)
LexToken(text,' ',1,89)
LexToken(sp,'\r',1,90)
LexToken(newline,'\n',1,91)
LexToken(body_close,'</body',1,92)
LexToken(bigger,'>',1,98)
```

My problem is that `<h1 id="someid"`gets interpreted as "text", and

```
LexToken(h1_open,'<h1)
LexToken(id_att, 'id=')
LexToken(id, ' "someid" ')
LexToken(text,' Paragraph')
LexToken(p_close,'</p')
```

How can I achieve that? I already defined h1_open, p_close and id_att as "reserved", thinking that  they would be identified separately, in the same way that p_open and body_open have worked. I'm not understanding why it doesn't work the same way with other tokens.

Comment: HTML parsing is non-trivial, and even if you constrain yourself to xhtml it’s going to be a challenge to roll your own parser. But asking this question without even hinting which lexing library you are using or showing your actual code seems very very optimistic. What research have you done?

Comment: @barny: OP is using ply, and has correctly tagged the question with [tag:ply].

Comment: @agus: what do you think the underscores mean in `r'[a-zA-Z_0-9_<_"][a-zA-Z_0-9_"]*'`?

Comment: @rici  I was interpreting the underscores as an "or", meaning the character could either be a letter, a number, a "<" or a quotation mark. Now I realize that was wrong. I will correct it

Answer (score 0):

All you have done is added `<h1` as a key to `reserved`. That doesn't make the string somehow special. It also doesn't change how a string containing `<h1` is matched by a regular expression. `<h1 id="someid"` is a match for your **text** pattern, and so the lexer executes the `t_text` action function.

On the whole, this is not the way to do lexical analysis. Lexical analysis should partition the input into lexemes, where each lexeme is a primitive. `<h1 id="someid"` is not a lexeme; it's probably five lexemes (`<`, `h1`, `id`, `=`, `"someid"`, assuming that whitespace has been discarded). The structure of the input will be analysed by the parser, and there should be no need to complicate your lexer in order to save a production or two.

HTML parsing generally requires that you use a different lexical state to handle the text outside of tags and the much more structured text which makes up a tag. You'll probably find that [lexical states](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn21) are helpful.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm seeing the problem now. `<h1 id="someid" `  is a match for text but in my reserved list I only have  `<h1`, which is not the same. I think will have to redefine my functions.